# Ld linker fails with absolute addressing error even though PIE is enabled

Tags: ios, ld, objective-c++, llvm-clang, arm64

For the past few days I've dealing with an issue I couldn't get my head around. I'm trying to build an old (6 years!) iOS game project of mine and the linker fails with the following error:

`Absolute addressing not allowed in arm64 code but used in '-[Snip snap]' referencing '_NSFileModificationDate' for architecture arm64`

The referred class does call `NSDictionary` `-objectForKey:` with `NSFileModificationDate` as parameter. It's an Objective-C++ source file since it does include C++ code.

So as I far as I understand, the linker considers that I compiled my sources to be position-dependent and fails, as intended with arm64. But why is that?

What I've tried or checked so far:

- Build settings:

  - Linking > Generate Position-Dependent Executable: `NO`
  - Linking > Other Linker Flags: `-all_load` `-ObjC`
  - Apple Clang - Code Generation > Generate Position-Dependent Code: `NO`
- do `clean` and delete `DerivedData` folder before rebuilding after any changes
- removed all third-party both static and dynamic libraries. I'm just using a few Apple frameworks
- removed any source files which were including `asm` code
- looked for any unknown-to-me preprocessor directives
- recreated the whole project from scratch and copying my source files in it, to make sure my older project has broken settings
- any `.m` or `.mm` source files which includes a constant just like that `NSFileModificationDate` will fail at linking
- `otool -hv` gives:

  `magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags`
  `MH_MAGIC_64   ARM64        ALL  0x00      OBJECT     4       3000 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS`

Here is the compilation command for the faulty file (sorry, that's verbose):

```
CompileC SNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Snip.o SNIPDesktop/SNIP/SNIP/Classes/App/Snip.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target: SNIP)
cd SNIPDesktop/SNIP/SNIP
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c++ -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu++14 -stdlib=libc++ -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=SNIPLibrary/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=SNIPLibrary/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -miphoneos-version-min=12.0 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -fembed-bitcode-marker -index-store-path SNIP/Index/DataStore -iquote SNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/SNIP-generated-files.hmap -ISNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/SNIP-own-target-headers.hmap -ISNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/SNIP-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote SNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/SNIP-project-headers.hmap -ISNIP/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -ISNIPDesktop/SNIP/SNIP/External -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2 -ISNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -ISNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/DerivedSources -FSNIP/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -include SNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/12134743132148408221/SNIP_prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF SNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Snip.d --serialize-diagnostics SNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Snip.dia -c SNIPDesktop/SNIP/SNIP/Classes/App/Snip.mm -o SNIP/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SNIP.build/Debug-iphoneos/SNIP.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Snip.o
```

What am I missing? What other clues should I look for? Is there any warning messages I should check?

Thanks for your much-appreciated help!

Comment: So I've succeeded to work around that issue by replacing all the references to frameworks constant variables with their actual values... this is not the solution but my quickfix.